# Firebase retrieves null data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from the Firebase realtime database. But the result is always null. I don't know the reason why the result is null. I got a firebase manager script and im just calling the variables from that script. It's my first time doing firebase and it's my first game project in unity too. Hope someone can enlighten me.

```
public class Player : Monobehaviour 
{
public FirebaseUser user;
public DatabaseReference reference;
public int level;
public int exp;
public Text levelText;
public Text expText;

void Start()
{
    user = GameObject.Find("Firebase Manager").GetComponent<FirebaseManager>().User;
    reference = GameObject.Find("Firebase Manager").GetComponent<FirebaseManager>().DBreference;
    StartCoroutine(LoadUserData());
}

void Update()
{
   levelText.text = level.ToString();
   expText.text = exp.ToString();
}

private IEnumerator LoadUserData()
{
    var DBTask = reference.Child("users").Child(user.UserId).GetValueAsync();

    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

    if(DBTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
    }
    else if(DBTask.Exception == null)
    {
       level = 1;
       exp = 0;
       Debug.Log("NullResult");
    }
    else
    {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;

        level = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Level").ToString());
        exp = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Exp").ToString());
    }

   
}
}
```

Comment: Why if `if(DBTask.Exception == null)` you don't use the results? Wouldn't this be the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do. i notice you forgot the .Value.ToString(); if you don't put the Value before ToString for sure it wont work.

```
else if(DBTask.Result.Exist)
{
   DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
   level = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Level").Value.ToString());
   exp = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Exp").Value.ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written in a way that it'll never execute the third block:

```
if(DBTask.Exception != null)
{
    Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
}
else if(DBTask.Exception == null)
{
   level = 1;
   exp = 0;
   Debug.Log("NullResult");
}
else
{
    DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;

    level = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Level").ToString());
    exp = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Exp").ToString());
}
```

See how the second `if` is the inverse of the first? That's probably not what you want, but it ensures that the unconditioned `else` block will never get executed.

My guess is that you want to have a second condition like this:

```
else if(DBTask.Result.Exists)
```

So that the second block runs if the task completed, but there was no data at the path in the database.

*Note: typos and small mistakes are possible, so please keep the reference documentation ready while testing this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query*.

Comment: thanks sir @Frank van Puffelen, the result is not null anymore. But another problem occur. The retrieve data is always 0 for exp and level. Even thou in the database it is not 0 for exp and level.